# Selenium Grid 2 - Remote webdriver not setting the user agent preference in FireFox

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, preference

I am using selenium server 2.28 on windows machine. I have set up the hub and node. I am using .net to write my test cases. I am using the following code to use custom FireFox (17.0.1) Profile with the user agent changed(to iPhone).

```
FirefoxProfileManager profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile profile = profileManager.GetProfile(FireFox_Profile_Name);
profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", _sUserAgent);
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
capability.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);
```

And I am instantiating a `RemoteWebDriver` instance like this:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("hub_uri"), capability);
```

When I check the `about:config` in the instance of firefox on the node machine, I don't see the general.useragent.override preference at all. If i use:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The preference is set correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you also try looking at the useragent value at whatsmyuseragent.com from the browser instantiated by webdriver? Just to make sure..?

Comment: A.J, I just checked and the user agent hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to do something very similar at the moment (setting Firefox to use Windows authentication).

In my (somewhat limited) experimentation to make this work, using just `profile` will work with a local driver instance, but not when talking to Selenium Server. I can get the profile to be passed to Selenium Server by using `profile.ToBase64String()` as hinted to [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#WebDriver).

Comment: Thanks @jheppinstall that worked (although not completely). When I use the existing profile and pass it using `ToBase64String()`, I get an error on the grid hub `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected...  but got...`. I created a new profile and then made changes to the profile's preferences before converting it using `ToBase64String()'. This way I was able to pass the profile to the node.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to pass the user agent in Grid 2 using Python.  If you don't want the proxy, just remove it.

```
    myProxy = IP:PORT
    proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'ftpProxy': myProxy,
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
        })

    desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()   
    browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()          
    browser_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", 'USERAGENT' )           
    desired_capabilities["firefox_profile"] = browser_profile.update_preferences() 
    driver = webdriver.Remote(   command_executor='http://IPADDRESS:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, browser_profile=browser_profile, proxy = proxy)
```

Hope that helps