# Selenium start chrome and enable extension

Tags: python, selenium, automation, slide

We have extension that we are testing and when i run the code with selenium it open the browser with the extension and now i need to enable it with a slide to right.

I thought i can do it with Inspect ( xpath,elemts,id or etc..) but as i can see i don't get the Inspect from the Extension button when i right click on it, and from the extension after that too.
[image]

But inside the extension i have a Slide to move to the right to start it, on the Slide i can export the Inspect information, but what i need to use to slide it to the right side?

[image]

Basically this is how my code starts:

```
op = Options()
op.add_extension('../extension/extension_21_9_0_0.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=op)
move = ActionChains(driver)
#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium cannot target the extensions menu, you can simulate a click using [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks) to make it work.

Comment: So yes, i watched a couple of videos about pyautogui and it's helped. Thanks
The only issue is i prefer to put this working in the background, and not touching my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of this where it "it depends".

Selenium will struggle to interact with an extension popup because it's a essentially opens extensions prompts in a different html page.

Chrome Extensions (v2) work with the concept of `background pages`. Chrome extensions (v3) work with `service workers`.  You should figure out which you're using so you can identify the best solution.

At this point, without knowing your extension, I would suggest a couple of options :

1/ When you click the slider, it will fire some JS. Look at the code, figure out where the calls is and you fire the same JS.

If needsbe, on the devtools sources tab, you can pause execution before you do your action to track down the call chain:

[image: devtools breakpoint controls]

2/ Open your extension page in a normal page.

Manually inspect your extension page and on devtools console type `document.location`
That will give you the local extension page chrome is running - for example:

```
...
href: "chrome-extension://ojhcleddagaoaplflbafhpekcciikdop/popup.html"
origin: "chrome-extension://ojhcleddagaoaplflbafhpekcciikdop"
pathname: "/popup.html"
...
```

Throw that href in your selenium navigation and you should have a page you can interact with.

Updating the version of the chrome extension does not update that identifier.  I've done development on a chrome extension and I've never seen mine change - no idea what it actually takes to update it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is possible, just use `driver.get("chrome://extensions/?id=pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii")`where the `pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii` should be replaced by the id of your extension. Then you can enable/disable the extension by clicking the corresponding button in that page.

If you just want to change the setting of the extension instead of fully disable it, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224995/9758790)